# Using width instead br and centering text

Tags: css

[image]

Hello, I am trying to style the h1 in two different parts, share your dream and Holiday dream.
I am centering the text using the text-align center in the main tittle class, this center the text in just one line, when I add width 45% to the h1 I achieve having two lines but the text-aligns center stop working.
I don't want to use `<br>` and I have been told to use width percentages but the problem is it is not center anymore.
Thank you

Comment: That makes sense , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text-align still works, it will center the text **inside** the element.

You change the width of the element, therefor it appears to be off center. So, you'll need to center the element as well. Add `margin: 0 auto` to the element and it should be working again.

Answer (score 0):

Your text are already aligned in center, it's your div i.e. `.main-tittle` not `aligned center` to aligned that center use `margin:auto;`

```
.main-tittle{
 width:45%; /* try to use pixels px value over-here instead of percentage */
 margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Why should it be in px? A percentage value works great as well, and responsively...

Comment: @LinkinTED Yes agree that percentage works perfect and responsively too, but over-here he didn't declared h1 tag twice instead made changes and aligned that text using width and that width at some point i.e. at higher vw it will break and text-alignment will differ, so px would work fine in this case :-)